# Delete sections without scroll down

Tags: ios, tableview

I am doing a small application using `UITableView` there are 2 sections in my `TableView`. In the last row of my first section, there is a `UISegmentControl`, one segment means delete section 2 and another is do nothing. In the `viewDidLoad` method, the segment is in the choice of "Do nothing", and when I click the "delete" segment. The section 2 is deleted, my question is can I keep the table still when and after I delete the section 2, I searched a lot about this question and I took much time on this. But still cannot find a solution to realize this effect. My code is as below:

```
CGPoint offset1 = [self.tableView contentOffset];
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1];           
_deleteSec = YES;
[self.tableView deleteSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

[self.tableView setContentOffset:offset1 animated:NO];
```

After the application start, my first action is to scroll up the `TableView` by hand. Then I click the delete segment, the above code was executed, the section 2 was deleted, but the `TableView` was scrolled to the initial location which is when the app just start and the `TableView` first show. I searched the Internet, I found the some code which I think will work to solve my issue. So I added them like below:

```
[self.tableView deleteSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];

[self.tableView setContentOffset:offset1 animated:NO];
```

This time, when I first time click the delete segment, it can keep still and delete the section 2, but when I click the other segment or anywhere else, the segment action method was not executed, the tableview just also scroll to the initial location itself, this seems wired to me. Can someone explain me this phenomenon? How to solve this issue? Thanks a lot if you can help me clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

This line right here:

```
[self.tableView deleteSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

try removing it.

You're telling the table to animate, so it will. If you just tell it to reload the data, it will not animate but the content in the table will be updated.

Comment: It does not work after I remove the code you mentioned, it has the same symptom as I said in the question.

Comment: Did you also remove (or comment out) the `setContentOffset:animated:`?